# enterprise apps on iphone4 ios9.1

Tags: ios, mobile, mobile-safari

**Situation:**

- company asset/ product, I am tryin to manage, but am not an Apple
  tech-tree person
- app binary is deployed to an apache host with https
- have the manifest & index file (can attach if that will help)
- Apache is setup to issue MIME mandated Content-types
- app objective-C code is unchanged for a month
- if I download it on a desktop, the file is a standard zip as expected for an IPA
- in previous version this process lead to an installable app; currently the app doesnt load.

How do I diagnose?  I will update this with an iconsole log.
Apache says everything is downloading correctly, despite the frontend saying "App downloaded incorrectly."

EDIT: My notifications at home have a request for the additional files; but this request isnt present here in the office.

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
            <dict>
                    <key>assets</key>
                    <array>
                            <dict>
                                    <key>kind</key>
                                    <string>software-package</string>
                                    <key>url</key>
                                    <string>https://nyetimberstock.com/ipa/StockRecorder.ipa</string>
                            </dict>
                    </array>
                    <key>metadata</key>
                    <dict>
                            <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                            <string>com.molewood.nyetimber</string>
                            <key>bundle-version</key>
                            <string>0.0</string>
                            <key>kind</key>
                            <string>software</string>
                            <key>title</key>
                            <string>Stocked</string>
                    </dict>
            </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The relevent line in the index

```
 <div class="link"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://nyetimberstock.com/ipa/manifest.plist">Tap Here to Install<br />Stocked<br />On Your Device</a></div>
```

Comment: Can you attach the manifest and index file?

Comment: @rhythmic-fistman, pls see update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manifest and html file look fine - the problem is that your app entitlements don't match the ones in your provisioning profile.

It looks your app was a debug build, while the provisioning profile you chose when exporting the ipa was a wildcard distribution in-house profile.

That can't end well.

Make sure in `Edit Schemes...` that the `Archive` command is using a release configuration (or make sure you're not overriding with a dev provisioning profile in Build Settings) and archive and export again.

I would also avoid using wildcard provisioning profiles when exporting the ipa. Try a distribution profile with an explicit app identifier instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try this.  Assuming it works, i will update this.

Comment: Did one test build, didn't work, our app guy is trying another build solution

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to update this.  That is kind of what I did, but by now I can't remember.